# Creating a dialog for Word Addin

Tags: c#, dialog, visual-studio-2005, ms-word, vsto

How can I create a Settings dialog for a Word Addin.

I have already creating a `Windows Form` and I'm calling 'form.Show()`. But It's creating a new Window.

How can I pass the owner by `form.ShowDialog(owner)`?

I've solve my question creating a Helper for open the Dialog, but I don't know if is the best way

```
public static DialogResult ShowDialog(Form dialog)
{
    NativeWindow mainWindow = new NativeWindow();
    mainWindow.AssignHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle);
    DialogResult dialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog(mainWindow);
    mainWindow.ReleaseHandle();
    return dialogResult;
}
```

Comment: I only create a Windows Form and called `Show()` method!

Comment: Can you explain more in detail what you mean by how do I create form.ShowDialog(owner) are you creating a custom form..? if so then you will need to create the form / call that creation thru code.. for example design the form and then call it dynamically is this what you are talking about..? I am a bit confused by what you have please show what code you have a visual will make it easier for others to Chime in...

Comment: I just created a simple Windows Form. Take a look in my question again, I solve the question. I don't know is the best way...

Comment: but you can simply call `form.ShowDialog();` and it will work!

Comment: No @FH4! If you simple call form.ShowDialog(), you only create a new Dialog. If you execute the code as answer, you will see a different behaviour, as a child dialog! The answer is not make it works, We should make better! :)

Comment: looks the same, can you describe what is the difference

Comment: looks the same to me as well, @Victor what different behavior you mean?

Comment: This question was made 3 years ago. I realy don't remember.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solve the question creating the code:

```
public static DialogResult ShowDialog(Form dialog)
{
    NativeWindow mainWindow = new NativeWindow();
    mainWindow.AssignHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle);
    DialogResult dialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog(mainWindow);
    mainWindow.ReleaseHandle();
    return dialogResult;
}
```